# Default page in Apache + Passenger + Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ruby-on-rails-3.1, passenger

In the end of the apache2.conf i added :

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/rusik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/rusik/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby

ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName sample.app
      DocumentRoot /home/rusik/work/ruby/sample_app/public
</VirtualHost>
```

So , when i restarted apache

```
sudo  apachectl restart
```

I got default apache page ,not rails project default page ,why ? 
[The default file](http://pastebin.com/QCD4aVQv) in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default , where are default virtual hosts i  didn't change .

Comment: What url are you putting into your browser ? It need's to match the ServerName (or alias) in your virtualHost block or else the default one will take precedence.

Comment: i am putting "localhost"

Comment: if i will add ServerAlias sample2.app after ServerName in VirtualHost block and put sample2.app in browser it will be not work . i tried ))

Comment: have your added sample2.app to you /etc/hosts ?

Comment: ok..i added(127.0.0.1 sample2.app), restarted , and now i am seeing: 403 forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. In log apache "..unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable .." . I try sudo chmod 777 /home/rusik/work/.htaccess but the error is the same - 403 . .htaccess was empty after chmod , but ,before ,it was not exists.

Comment: ok i added permission on folders : work,ruby,sample_app and it works! Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put

```
<Directory /home/rusik/work/ruby/sample_app/public>
   AllowOverride none
   Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

within  and restart the server?

Answer (score 0):

Also add... **Options FollowSymLinks**

```
<Directory ... >
    ...
    Options FollowSymLinks

</Directory>
```